# Не могу прогнать шрифты через вебпак,как решить такой Error?

Tags: javascript, webpack

[image: Cтруктура папок]

Вот такие ошибкы выбивает [введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmsdf.png)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

.webpack.base.conf.js

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')


const PATHS = {
  src: path.join(__dirname, '../src'),
  dist: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
  assets: 'assets/'
}

const PAGES_DIR = PATHS.src
const PAGES = fs
  .readdirSync(PAGES_DIR)
  .filter(fileName => fileName.endsWith('.html'))

module.exports = {
  externals: {
    paths: PATHS
  },
  entry: {
    app: PATHS.src
  },
  output: {
    filename: `${PATHS.assets}js/[name].[contenthash].js`,
    path: PATHS.dist,
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          name: 'vendors',
          test: /node_modules/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules/'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: { sourceMap: true }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              config: { path: `./postcss.config.js` }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: { sourceMap: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: { sourceMap: true }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              config: { path: `./postcss.config.js` }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': PATHS.src,
      '@': `${PATHS.src}/js`, 
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: `${PATHS.assets}css/[name].[contenthash].css`
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: `${PATHS.src}/${PATHS.assets}img`,
          to: `${PATHS.assets}img`
        },
        {
          from: `${PATHS.src}/${PATHS.assets}fonts`,
          to: `${PATHS.assets}fonts`
        },
        {
          from: `${PATHS.src}/static`,
          to: ''
        }
      ]
    }),
    ...PAGES.map(
      page =>
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: `${PAGES_DIR}/${page}`,
          filename: `./${page}`
        })
    )
  ]
}
```

Comment: Юзаю команду npm run build

Comment: Покажите папочку `fonts`, что внутри?